# Keeping controller in scope

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Yesterday i was working on my asp.net mvc application where i was trying to cache some data in a field while a certain controller was in scope. The field kept clearing every time a new view got opened.

Question: 
Is it possible to keep your Controller in scope while you're browsing Views that are handled by said Controller?

```
private static List<string> _listOfStrings;

[Authorize]
public ActionResult ToView1()
{
    _listOfStrings = new List<String>(){"test","test2"};

    var model = new Model();
    return View(model);
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult FromView1ToView2()
{
    var model = new Model(_listOfStrings);
    //the issue at hand is that '_listOfStrings' is not persisted.
    return View(model);
}
```

Anyone got an idea if this is possible? (The list is big, so i would prefer not sending it through the model into the view and vice versa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read about an [ASP.NET MVC lifecycle](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application).

Short answer: no, you can't cause `Controller` is destroyed after a call of an action. Detail answer: you can store (cache) data in a [`TempData`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option) or in a [`Session`](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-5) properties.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i expected as much... I'll try out the TempData but i'm afraid it will be too flighty. Session, i'm not that big of a fan of.

Comment: You can use TempData in two sequence actions. In a second action you can rewrite TempData and therefore you can use it in a third action and so on.

Comment: @Yaw `TempData` is `Session`! (except it only lasts one request so if the user refreshes the browser its gone)

Answer (score 0):

_listOfStrings is a different variable to listOfStrings. You are not writing to or reading from the static field. In the code you have presented, _listOfStrings is not even defined.

Use one static variable and this code will work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the type-o, but in my code it is written as you said, doesn't work because of the reason pointed out above.

Comment: I don't understand. Static fields are persisted regardless of objects being created and destroyed. If you put a breakpoint in your second method, _listOfStrings should be a list with 2 values in it.

Comment: I didn't understand either... that's why i posted the question. Read up on the article above, it provides a whole bunch of information.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. 

For example, I use a static field to make sure that only one request to import data from a webservice happens at once. If a second request is made, the static field "importInProgress" is already true and an error is returned.